# Why is vertical-align implemented the way it is?

Tags: html, css

When I attach `vertical-align: middle` to a DIV, I expect its contents to be vertically aligned. However, this is not what happens.

Many Stack Overflow threads exist about this seemingly odd behavior, but my question is different. Why was this CSS attribute implemented the way it was? Was it not meant to be a direct alternative to the deprecated `valign` tag?

Comment: For everyone's reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

Comment: You might also want to look at the `line-height` property. In certain situations you'll want to use one over the other, or even both in tandem.

Comment: @BoltClock - I've always associated this property with `display: table-cell`. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Not wrong, but it isn't exclusive to table cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align` seems to do the same as [valign](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-valign), as far as table-cells are concerned. (Additionally, it can be used on inline-elements to align them inside their [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#line-box).)

So I guess it was meant to be, and is, a replacement of the deprecated `valign`.

Both being "the same", I am unsure whether you misunderstand `valign` or I misunderstand your question.

Comment: "... it can be used on inline-elements to align them inside the parent". No, it can't. it can be used on inline elements to align them inside the [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#line-box)

Comment: But what's the logic for it behaving differently on things that aren't table cells? A casual observer might think this property lets them vertically center the contents of - say - a DIV.

Comment: And the casual observer will notice that it has no effect on the `div`; at this point (s)he will either go read about it or ignore the property. I don't know why it works differently in table-cells... and I guess this means my answer is useless to you? Sorry. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can get `vertical-align` in a div to work by using this DOC-TYPE. I don't know if it is recommended or if the DOC-TYPE is deprecated. But none-the-less it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what does the doctype have to do with `vertical-align`?

Comment: @BoltClock he was stating that when he places `vertical-align` on a div it doesn't work like you'd think, but in fact nothing happens. So I placed the DOC-TYPE up because for what ever reason the doc-type causes `vertical-align` to work on divs.